# Is there a way to prevent directory traversal attacks in a Shiny App running in Windows?

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard

I'm trying to develop an internal Shiny app for my organization as a test run. The IT department is requiring the app to be safe from [Directory Traversal Attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack). Unfortunately, I have to deploy the Shiny app in a Windows machine. (currently using runApp). 
I have searched but not found a way to implement the different recommendations of avoiding Directory Traversal Attacks. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Where is the app going to be hosted? is it just run with runapp on everyone's machine that is testing it? More details about your environment will help direct you to the proper setup.

Comment: It is going to be hosted at a private server. At the moment, for testing purposes, it is just run with runApp from the virtual machines connected to the server. But I'm open to suggestions that allow to fix the directory traversal problem, even if they app is not run with runApp.

Answer (score 0):

Protecting from a traversal attack is two fold. Once in the application and once in the system.

For the application, you will need to make sure that you are cleaning any inputs that point to a hosted file. For example, if your application allows a user to call images/supercool.png youll need to verify that the path is not being changed to something like ../../../../etc/psswd.

For the system, it is a matter of separating privileges. The accounts given access to the runapp files should not also have access to system files(beyond what is absolutely needed.

I would recommend using shiny server or connect to host the files for you, especially if you do not feel prepared to implement the needed security.

Rstudio has done a lot of work and a great job to make a good product and is continuing to add new features including enhancements around security/access.